# Is there a function to exclude certain sheets from my workbook from the script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a code to clear certain data cells `("F2:M95")` on a time-based trigger once a week. Everything works as I want it to except I noticed it's clearing the data from those particular cells on every sheet in my workbook.

This is the function I currently have:

```js
function LunchEmailClear() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActive()
  activeSheet.getRange("F2:M95").clear();
}
```

What can I add so that it will only apply to certain sheets? (i.e. "Morning Emails, Lunch Emails")

PS. Also sorry if I sound a bit dumbfounded, I just started messing around with scripts last week and hardly have any clue as to what I'm doing. I appreciate any help I can get! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation:

We can make use of the JavaScript `Array.indexOf()` method to achieve this.

In the script below I've an array of sheets we want to include and defined it as `var include`. We can then compare this array with the sheet names using a `for` loop running an `if` statement. This checks the sheet names against our array of inclusions using `Array.indexOf()`.

---

#### Example:

```js
function emailClear() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  //list sheets to include here
  var include = ['Morning Emails', 'Lunch Emails'];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (include.indexOf(sheets[i].getName()) > -1) {
      sheets[i].getRange("F2:M95").clear();
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### References:

- [`Spreadsheet.getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets())
- [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [`Sheet.getName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet.html#getName())

Comment: It's a valid approach too! Depending on if he wants to use a list of sheets to clear or sheets to maintain he can use your method or mine :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried out your method but when I ran it, it did nothing to my workbook

Comment: @AyssaHinojosa check your sheet names are correct - make sure there are no spaces at the beginning/end that you didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

This should works properly:

```
function LunchEmailClear() {
  //Add the list of sheets to clean
  var sheets = ['Morning Emails', 'Lunch Emails'] 
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  for (var i=0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    app.getSheetByName(sheets[i]).getRange("F2:M95").clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it out but it gave me an error, "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 7, file "Code")" do you know what my the problem?

Comment: Have you changed the sheets names, or do you have sheets called "Morning Emails" and "Luch Emails"? put the sheet names that you want to clear in the sheets variable

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I figured it out, it was an error on my part there was a space I had missed on the sheet name. @JuanBravoRoig you two are lifesavers and you made my workday all the better, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer has helped you please upvote and mark as valid! :)